# spring-boot:run throws ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am trying to get some simple REST services done, however I am having issues with spring-boot as it says ClassNotFoundException, here's some details:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>it.athirat</groupId>
<artifactId>sww2.1</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>it.athirat.controller.Application</start-class>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Application.java (under src/main/java/it/athirat/controller)

```
package it.athirat.controller;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building sww2.1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ sww2.1 >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ sww2.1 <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ sww2.1 ---
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: it.athirat.controller.Application
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:522)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.003 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-05-22T11:51:49+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/226M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.3.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project sww2.1: An exception occurred while running. it.athirat.controller.Application -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: which class not found. Put stacktrace

Comment: @pvpkiran Edited question, put stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can remove the `start-class`

```
<start-class>it.athirat.controller.Application</start-class>
```

Just have spring boot maven plugin and it will locate the `main` class on its own

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I had to remove <packaging>pom</packaging> too in order to make it work